# Why isn’t it obvious that the grammars of natural languages cannot be context-free?

Tags: grammar-formalism, context-free-grammars

I've read that a context-free grammar is one in which every production rule is written in the way **V** **->** **a**, where **V** is a non-terminal symbol and **a** is a chain of non-terminal and terminal symbols.

In English we have non-terminal symbols like **Verb**, **Adjective**, etc.

But in a sentence, almost all verbs have an extra **-s**,if the subject is in the third person singular.

How could this be accounted for by a context-free grammar?

If English grammar was context-free, it would have production rules like **Verb** **->** **sing**, or **Verb -> sings** - but how could we correctly pick up **sing** or **sings** in a context-free grammar, if the left-hand side of the production rule must be a single non-terminal symbol, and hence cannot contain the subject of the sentence (at least not always)?

In other words, how can the word “sing” be properly transformed, when such a rule could not take into account other words in the context, like who the *subject* of the verb is?

Comment: Hypothesis: if all we want is a parser we can get a parser that produces a correct parse tree from valid sentences by ignoring noun-verb agreement.

Comment: People underestimate the power of *finite but unlimited* assets. Congruence is an obvious problem for CFG, and pseudo-parametrisation by multiplying out states is a (to computer scientists) obvious solution. The required number of states makes it totally impractical, but C.S. theory doesn't care about practical limits on something as long as it's not actually *infinite*.

Comment: @KilianFoth your comment sounds rich with insight, but is above my head for its technicality - I would really appreciate if you could elaborate, as I’m intrigued to know more, and I think the question could also benefit from it.

Comment: @KilianFoth If people recognise the existence of anything '…finite but unlimited…' can you say why Google doesn't recognise that wording?

Comment: Is anyone suggesting the only meaningful part of the Question is whether natural grammars 'cannot' be context-free? Conversely, are people denying that they could be, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imagine a very simple CFG that only handles nouns and verbs.

> S → N V
> N → dogs | cats | Alice | Bob
> V → walk | play | eat

Right now this can't handle agreement. But it can with a small change:

> S → N<sub>sing</sub> V s
> S → N<sub>pl</sub> V
> N<sub>sing</sub> → Alice | Bob
> N<sub>pl</sub> → dogs | cats
> V → walk | play | eat

Just add more categories! Now it correctly produces *Alice walks* but *cats walk*.

This is not a great solution. It gets unwieldy very quickly when you have more forms of agreement to deal with. But it works well enough, in general, that it's not obvious that it can't work in every case.

Comment: Thank you!  right, of course, it was stupid to assume that the context-free production rule cannot contain the subject and the predicate in the right-hand side.

Comment: This helps me understand “context-free” in a simple way I had not, before. Context-free literally means “unary operator” in math. You can map an element to another but the mapping does not take more than one argument. A function f(x, y) is “context-dependent” because it is the same as an if-conditional: *if* x=3, *then* f(x, y)=7. A grammar that chooses the replacement for an incoming sequence *depending on* the presence of a nother symbol is exemplifying an “if”-clause. It took me a while to see how simple that is. I like the term “transcription machine” - the simplest level of “translation”.

Comment: More likely specify categories Vsing and Vpl, rather than hard-coding the suffix.

Comment: @hmltn That is not a bad way to see it, however keep in mind that thanks to the technique of "currying", formally there is no need to ever need more than one argument. E.g. you can first apply the argument 3 to generate the partial function f(3,.) and then evaluate that at y and so on. In fact that is precisely what happens in this answer. The only caveat that prevents this from always working in the context of grammars is that there is only a finite number of symbols allowed, which in this case translates to finitely many different possibilities of f(x,.).

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I understand that totally (out of a desire to learn more). What you describe as “currying” to me sounds like it requires a concept of “partial function” - an object that is a function with two arguments, but only one of them (yet) selected. But that still qualifies as a function which is defined in terms of 2 arguments, right? A formal system which truly has no concept of binary mappings, not even partial ones, could never emulate the characteristics of a conditional (I think). You either have f(x) = a, a 0-level type (terminal, non-predicative, a set element or number

Comment: ), or f(x) = g(x) - I suppose if you can map a value to a variety of functions as of yet unevaluated, then what you are saying is true. Still, I think I am trying to say something that needs better formulation. There is a mathematical class, in set theory, or type theory, that can never perform something “like” a conditional. In light of currying (thank you for pointing it out), then maybe we have to say, a function is not permitted to return a function as its value. Type-1 elements must be defined with type-0 in their codomain. Do you think so? Thank you

Comment: “The only caveat that prevents this from always working in the context of grammars is that there is only a finite number of symbols allowed, which in this case translates to finitely many different possibilities of f(x,.).” I don’t follow. Do you mean to say, this is precisely why “unrestricted grammars” (Chomsky type-0, equivalent to Turing-complete) are of a higher “capability” (can express more “messages”) - because they are permitted recursion (and thus, infinitude) - again, is it a matter of formulation? If a context-free grammar on an infinite alphabet = unrestricted on a finite one…

Comment: then the classification is, again, sort of.. missing the bigger picture; would you agree? Like, if the functions permit infinitude, we can work with finite symbols. If the symbols are infinite, we can work with finite functions.. this seems clearly to be an equivalence.. it depends how you define what a “function” even is. In set theory, you can define functions straight from sets (the set of pairs the mapping associates to each other).. perhaps… it is a matter of set cardinality? True CFG are FINITE SETS, true unrestricted grammars are INFINITE.. could it be that simple??? I wonder.

Comment: Now I guess I understand how this bears on the OP’s great question.. the debate about the infinitude of language is because we aren’t sure that there isn’t a finite but very big list of rules describing the variety for forms of English. An intriguing thought, I guess. Or, is it easily dismissed, after all? I’m not sure right now.

Answer (score 4):

1. Nothing in mathematics is *ever* obvious until after it is proven.

1.1 This is one reason English not being a CFG is not *"obvious"*.

2. A **right-linear grammar** can generate English, because a right-linear grammar over some alphabet, can generate all possible strings of that alphabet.

2.1 A right-linear grammar can generate all of the strings of English - it can actually generate *more* sentences than just the sentences of English. You can't just be concerned with whether a grammar of a certain type can generate a certain class of strings. The question has to be more specifically about *exact* generation. Can grammar G generate a certain class of strings, and not generate other stuff? Is it possible to generate English and *only* English, with some right-linear grammar? Or, can a suggested grammar also generate Mohawk? Or generate some other language? The supposed grammar does not succeed, when it *over*-generates - when it generates more strings, or sentences, than are considered allowable or correct, in the language.

2.2 The correctness of a formal grammar, or a theory of grammar, is that it generates exactly the sentences of a language L - no more, and no less.

3. There is a reasonably easy-to-come-up-with solution to the grammatical feature you mentioned regarding noun-verb agreement for *number* (which @Draconis provides). But does this type of solution generalize to all human languages?

3.1 [Shieber 1985](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Eshieber/Biblio/Papers/shieber85.pdf) provides evidence against that context-freeness claim. Their argument comes from Swiss German data. And there is a similar argument proffered in [Culy 1985]. Their argument is based on data from Bambara.

4. You can easily tell from inspection of a grammar whether it is context-free or context-sensitive.

4.1 But the reverse is not true: you cannot easily tell from inspection of a set of strings, whether or not that exact set can or cannot be generated by a context-free grammar. We don't really fully yet understand what kinds of languages can and cannot be generated by C.S. vs. C.F. grammars. At least when explained in ordinary linguistic terms.

4.2 We don't really know what kind of facts could constitute an "impossible language" for CF grammar. Though Culy and Shieber have given us some suggestions. In short, none of this is "obvious".

Comment: I'll try to respectfully do some minor edits on this answer, if it'd be alright, because it's a very good answer, I'd just like to try to expand each of the points you made. Of course, feel free to revert if you don't like the edits, I would welcome that. Thank you.